# Webview does not display anything in React native (expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I am trying to use webview but somehow does not display anything.

I tried importing webview on react native and also tried import using react-native-webview 
but still can't find any good solution. (using expo)

You could check my sample snacks:

https://snack.expo.io/rkuhXxLwB => using import { WebView } from 'react-native'

https://snack.expo.io/HksNveIwr => using import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

Please Note: I have also tried to test this on my actual device but same result

Appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Using react-native-webview : the React-Native-Web in expo has bugs, try it on an emulator or on your device

Comment: i tested on android both snacks  and page was displayed. Did you test on IOS and what  version of SDK are  you using?

Comment: I ran the snack sample on my Iphone and the emulator, with react-native-weview, it was working just fine

Answer (score 0):

import webview from rect-native

`import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';`